# How to track the device's position and orientation in physical space using ARFoundation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am new to AR Foundation, in ARcore we are getting device position using

```
Vector3 currentARPosition = Frame.Pose.position;
```

like this how-to get device position in Arfoundation ? for ArCore and Arkit both?